# Salesforce VScode retrieve from org "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I was using the "Retrieve source in manifest from org" command for the resources in package.xml file. However when I executed the command it failed saying "Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". There are no errors in the package file. I have authorized the org, reinstalled salesforce extension and the issue remains.

Comment: Is your sfdx up to date? You should run `sfdx update` to make sure it is.

Comment: Can you post your package file?

Comment: @DerekF tried sfdx update and it did not fix it

Comment: @NicholasSavini 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
  <members>Account.Business_Email__c</members>
  <name>CustomField</name>
 </types>
 <version>49.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: And what command are you running? It's helpful to add to edit you post and add it in there.

Comment: I had the same problem while trying to retrieve SharingSets with a manifest file from the Visual Studio Code menu. Updating sfdx didn't help. Luckily retrieving it from the command line worked.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution here : https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9064S000000kFosQAE

```
Karol Dylewski
Issue started with new Salesforce CLI Integration extension pack update.

As a solution, install previous version of this package

1. VScode -> Extensions (ctr shift x)
2. Find Salesforce CLI Integration
3. Click Uninstall dropdown, and then Install Another Version
4. I tried with 51.8.0 and now it works
```