# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: apex, vs-code, trailhead

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/get-started-with-salesforce-development/get-ready-to-develop

I am following the project on Trailhead,

---

[image]

---

when I was trying to "Execute Anonymous Apex", it does not shown in my vscode. Then I pressed `ctrl+shift+p`and selected `sfdx: execute anonymous apex with editor contents`, it showed `Unexpected error while executing anonymous apex. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`
I have completely followed all the steps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your getRecordMethod code here?

Comment: I've seen this issue from two different causes, I believe; either with the version of the sfdx CLI you are using (try upgrading to latest and, if necessary try uninstalling and reinstalling), or there's a problem with the org you are connecting to. For scratch orgs, when we see this error we throw the scratch org away and create a replacement. I believe the CLI is not getting back the response it expects (gets a null response or response not containing an expected property) and so it fails when trying to process that response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce VScode retrieve from org "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342854/salesforce-vscode-retrieve-from-org-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your VS studio and run the commands again. It works for me !

Answer (score 0):

This exact error just happened to me and I had to re-auth the org that was causing problems.